# Does Lync support AES-256 for media encryption?

Tags: media, lync, skype-for-business

I want to check AES-256 media encryption with Lync clients .Is it supported?

Answer (score 0):

One way to check is to check the SDP of a Lync Client invite:

Version of my currently installed client:

> user-agent: UCCAPI/16.0.4732.1000 OC/16.0.4732.1000 (Skype for
> Business)

Crypto options advertised in the SDP:

> a=cryptoscale:1 client AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:KddgDX9mxaeLYuYHoKUk85nzcKqvd8+cFp+XMliD|2^31|1:1
>
> a=crypto:2 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:KddgDX9mxaeLYuYHoKUk85nzcKqvd8+cFp+XMliD|2^31|1:1
>
> a=crypto:3 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:KddgDX9mxaeLYuYHoKUk85nzcKqvd8+cFp+XMliD|2^31

So as of Lync Client version 16.0.4732.1000, no it doesn't.